# Can we rename this site to be more inclusive of Linux ARM hardware?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

I think there is a *lot* of overlap between questions that will be asked on this site concerning the Raspberry Pi, and questions related to other similar hardware such as the BeagleBone, PandaBoard, etc.

I'd like to propose that we rename this site to something more inclusive. My example would be the [elinux wiki](http://elinux.org/Main_Page) that includes sections for Raspberry Pi as well as similar hardware.

What are peoples thoughts on this?

Including the rest of the mini-ARM hardware community could only help this site grow stronger.

Comment: I wish people would answer "No" and upvote that instead of just downvoting the question... it's a good question if you ask me

Comment: There is a convention that upvoting/downvoting represent agreeing and disagreeing respectively on SE meta.

Comment: It may be an important question, but it's one that is not entirely applicable at this time and may be more useful to discuss later on.  This was discussed in length in the proposal and so far there's no evidence that the site won't be adequately successful and useful in its current scope.

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/370/should-this-site-merge-with-the-embedded-programming-design-proposal), which talks about a merger with [this site](https://embedded.stackexchange.com/). Questions about hardware other than the Pi could likely be asked there.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should stick to Raspberry Pi hardware/software. I expect there to be enough interest so that we don't need to branch out.

Answer (score 5):

## Not yet

If the site is capable of success as an exclusively Raspberry Pi SE, there is no reason to consider diluting its usefulness.  That being said, there are a few other reasons to consider for keeping it exclusively Raspberry Pi, other than "because it can be":

- Ubiquity: The Raspberry Pi is already well-known and relatively widespread
- Community: This device specifically has already generated a strong community, which can contribute to the success of an SE site
- Question topics: A site specifically geared towards Raspberry Pi is much more likely to attract questions and answers relevant to the device.  In addition, if converted to a "more inclusive" site, there are two issues of dilution.  One is that the Raspberry Pi community may have a tougher time finding answers on the site, especially ones specific to the device.  The other is a conversion now would likely result in a site that "Covers all Linux  ARM hardware" but in reality contains mostly Raspberry Pi questions, diminishing the site's usefulness to both the specific community and the Linux ARM hardware community at-large.

Comment: Thank you for putting thought into this answer. I don't entirely agree, but I understand the position and appreciate you sharing. I think one of my biggest issues with the site being RasPi specific is with regards to lifespan. RasPi is one product. It will end, probably soon. If subsequent Pi's get released, then this is acceptable. If not, we have a dead Q&A site with a lot of relevant content for other ARM hardware.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit on my lifespan comment. If you look at all of the other SE sites, they all cover a brand, theme, or idea that is more or less unending. You don't for example see a "Windows 7" site. Or a "Dell Optiplex 600" site. You might see a "Windows" or "Dell" site though. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I understand the concern, but I think that still falls under the "Not Yet" category.  Products don't die all at once, and this doesn't look like it's going anywhere anytime soon.  If it begins to become a problem, expansion or migration is a possibility, but expecting a product to die when weighing the relevance of a SE is not a fair assumption without any evidence to the fact.

Comment: It seems that is the majority opinion. Measure twice, cut once is all I'm suggesting. Time will tell. All in all it really isn't a big deal though. :)

Comment: I'll also note that no "Linux ARM Hardware" proposal got enough definition or commitment to enter beta.  A "Raspberry Pi" proposal did.  The power of the name and the community surrounding the specific device is what launched this site.

Answer (score 4):

I expect that a lot of hardware issues are going to come up, and renaming the site will complicate the answers.

Comment: This was two years ago. I would be interested to know if the site has become what you expected.